# User Mode Linux on ARM

Tags: arm, user-mode-linux, uml

I usually use `UML` but seems ARM architecture doesn't support it.

Can I use UML on ARM? Before this I shared tiny servers with my friends.
Now, I bought ARM based server.

Anybody knows how to use UML on ARM based PC?

Comment: Do you know if ARM is supported yet?

Answer (score 1):

UML is only supported on x86/x86_64:

http://sourceforge.net/p/user-mode-linux/mailman/message/32782012/

Try KVM/ARM instead?